# Energy transfer from Engine exhaust gas to hot water

Tags: thermodynamics, gas, heat-engine

I am looking at  waste heat recovery from gas fuelled engine exhaust. 
I am using a data sheet for a Jenbacher J620 engine-.  I assume the engine exhaust flows out through some kind of waste heat boiler and then to atmosphere. In the data sheet it is stated that;

Exhaust gas mass flow (wet) = 17325 kg hr ( not sure about the wet part?) this becomes 4.81 kg/s

Exhaust gas temperature = 425 degC

Recoverable thermal output (120 °C) = 3020 kw - I assume that means when exhaust gas is reduced to 120 deg C. 
This gives an overall efficiency of 86% (thermal Plus electrical) However when I apply the formula Qdot = mdot X CpX deltaT, I get 4.81 X 1.15 X 305, which only comes to 1688 Kw , about half the claimed value!?

The claimed value doesn’t seem unreasonable because a review of the literature seems to show overall CHP efficiencies of 70-80% are the norm. 
I did a mass weighting of different products of combustion of methane and 70% excess air to come up with that Cp,- a bit of a fudge, but its not that much difference to the Cp of straight air at 650K. 
The Cp would have to be about twice that to match the makers claimed figures for heat recovery and I don't think any errors or uncertainties in the Cp could be that much.

I must be missing something- but what ??.

The "other side" of the heat exchanger , shown in the  data sheet as "forward temperature, return temperature, hot water flow rate" , works out to the correct figure as per the claimed recoverable  heat.
But surely this heat added to the hot water must equal the heat removed from the exhaust gas.

Could it be something to do with "flow work"?- i.e. changes in  gas velocity in the heat exchanger. But all texts and references I have checked don't account for any flow work.

Extract from makers data sheet below;[image]

To calculate Cp, I first took the Cp of “Dry air at low pressure" at 650K
From the tables of Rogers and Mayhew- Thermodynamic and Transport Properties of Fluids 5th Ed. (image attached) This is 1.06 KJ/kgK , which  had also seen used as  ‘good enough approximation “ in a few google searches.

But to double check I made a few different weighted averages based on a few different air fuel mass ratios. You can see in second image ( am i right - there is no way to attach files such as excel in stack exchange?) where I played around with a few different fuel air ratios. There was no point being too exact as I don’t know exactly what fuel they are using. Its calorific value seems to be  at the lowest end of the range for natural gas.

But the point is, no reasonable assumptions I could make could get the Cp to be anything close to what is required for the energy to balance.
Working backwards that Cp would be  3020/(305 *4.81)= 2.05.

But there is no realistic scenario I can come up with where the flue gas would have a Cp of 2.05.- even 100% humidity. So I am thinking there must be something else I am missing?
[image: ?]
[image]

Comment: The problem must be in your determination of the heat capacity or in the estimate of the mass flow rate.  Please show more details on how you determined the heat capacity (composition of exhaust gas).

Comment: Thanks Chet , I have edited my post to show estimate of Cp. No need to estimate mass flow rate ,because it is given.

Comment: I'm as puzzled as you are.

Comment: Yes, I am wondering whether they are including heat recovered from lube oil and engine cooling water. I contacted makers ,but not confident I will get a reply.

Comment: Did not get a reply from makers but found obtained an updated data sheet from a colleague. the "missing kw" are indeed  from the Lube oil, inter cooler and jacket water cooler"